# Calculate sum of object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to create the dynamic calculator. The objective is to calculate the cost of raw materials when either quantity or the rate change;

React component to render the details:

`<CostOfRawMaterial/>` component renders the calculated cost:

I would like to update the same to the state. Find below the state details as well in the field costOfRawMaterial concurrently

```
  {recipeRawMaterials.map((material, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <GridContainenr key={index}>
              <RawMaterial>{material.rawMaterial}</RawMaterial>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  flexDirecction: 'row',
                  alignItems: 'baseline',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  marginLeft: '-10px'
                }}
              >
                <Quantity
                  type="text"
                  name="quantity"
                  defaultValue={material.quantityInRecipe}
                  onChange={handleQuantityChange(material._id)}
                />
                <QuantityUnit>{material.recipeUnit}</QuantityUnit>
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  flexDirecction: 'row',
                  alignItems: 'baseline',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
                }}
              >
                <Quantity
                  type="text"
                  value={material.rate}
                  onChange={handleRateChange(material._id)}
                />
                <BaseRateUnit>
                  /{material.baseQuantity}
                  {material.baseUnit}
                </BaseRateUnit>
              </div>
              <CostOfRawMaterial>
                {(material.rate * material.quantityInRecipe) /
                  material.baseQuantity}
              </CostOfRawMaterial>
              <DeleteIcon
                onClick={() => handleRemoveRawMaterial(material._id)}
                style={{ margin: '0' }}
              />
            </GridContainenr>
          </>
        );
      })}
```

Function used to update the quantity:

```
  const handleQuantityChange = id => e => {
    console.log(id);

    let tempArray = [...state.recipeRawMaterials];

    console.log(tempArray);

    tempArray
      .filter(rec => rec._id === id)
      .forEach(item => (item.quantityInRecipe = e.target.value));

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_RAWMATERIAL_PRICE,
      payload: tempArray
    });
  };
```

```
{"_id":"5f36c81b875da6156c9a077c",
"rawMaterial":"Sugar",
"brandName":"Cadbury",
"supplier":"Dasnya",
"type":"Solid",
"baseQuantity":500,
"baseUnit":"gm",
"rate":100,
"quantityInRecipe":"90",
"costOfRawMaterial":0,
"recipeUnit":"gm",
"__v":0}
```

Comment: what's the problem can you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: Would you please include an runnable example showing the issue you experience? You can use the https://codesandbox.io to create one.

Comment: Working on the same.. Will sharer one quickly